# How to play audio files from command line

Tags: audio, command-line

I'm looking for a simple command line tool to play audio files for the command line, I'm looking to play `.wav` files. I'd also like to be able to stream audio from http and pipe it into this tool. Does anyone have a tool that works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `afplay` to play audio files from the command line. Just run `afplay` in Terminal without any argument to display the internal help file.

```
$ afplay
Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
$
```

Comment: `➜  hello-streaming-audio ls
app.js  node_watson.wav
➜  hello-streaming-audio afplay node_watson.wav`
no sound is playing, does it work with wav files?