# How to play the audio of a .mkv file from a command line from a specific offset to another at different speeds

Tags: command-line, audio, mediaplayer

The first thing I tried was using VLC:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC '{$movpath}' --start-time='{$ts}' --stop-time='{$te}' --no-video rate='0.5' 2> /dev/null;
```

However, the player takes 10 seconds to load every time the command is executed, and this is too slow for my purpose as I am calling this command with shell_exec() from a PHP command line script.

I read: [How to play audio files from command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257869/how-to-play-audio-files-from-command-line), and tried `afplay`, but it doesn't recognise .mkv files.

Ideally I should not need pre-processing eg. should not need to use `ffmpeg` to extract the audio from the .mkv file first, as I have tried this, and it also takes too long for my purpose.

In addition, I do need to adjust the speed of the playback as well, as I need to play the file at various speeds (eg. 1x, 0.5x and 0.25x).

How might I achieve my aim?

Comment: How many mkv files are we looking at, how often do they change?

Comment: @nohillside it's the same file for maybe every 2-3 days

Comment: Would preprocessing the file (separating the audio track and maybe create different versions by speed) work?

Comment: hmm I have a few thousand of segments per file that must be played.. will preprocessing be too long?

Comment: Why not just try, without segments? If it starts up quickly then, all should be good.

Comment: ok will try that @nohillside